# Link two cmake projects next to each other

Tags: c++, cmake

Lets say I have two cmake libraries: `lib1` and `lib2`, where `lib2` **depends on** `lib1`. How can I do it without putting them into one general cmake project, meaning there should be only two CMakeLists.txt (one for lib1 and one for lib2) but not general CMakeLists.txt that link them together.

```
cmake_agnostic_root/
|-- lib1/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- include/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib2/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- include/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- (there must be no CMakeLists.txt on this level)
```

In my understanding there should be something inside `lib2`'s CMakeLists.txt only that will include `lib1`.

**What I tried** (nothing worked):

1. **add_subdirectory**:
   Tried to add this line to `lib2` cmake:

```
add_subdirectory(../lib1 lib1)
```

but `lib2` still can't find `lib1`'s headers

2. **ExternalProject**:
   Tried to add this lines to `lib2` cmake:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
  lib1
  SOURCE_DIR ../lib1
)
```

Probably I use this command wrong, as in all examples it downloads git repositories, but I need to use local folder `lib1` next to `lib2`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I want to call cmake in `lib2` that triggers `lib1` build and then use it to build `lib2`.

Comment: Not `add_subdirectory(../lib1 lib1)` but, `add_subdirectory(../lib1)`. That will work (explain why it doesn't for you), but is not a good practice. If you really don't want to have any root CMakeLists.txt that can build lib1, and then use that dependency in lib2, then you need to package your lib1, install it, and then find it with `find_package`, probably with hint in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, if you don't want it system-wise.

Comment: @pptaszni if I do add_subdirectory your way I'll get error: `add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source directory lib1 is not a subdirectory of lib2.  When specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly specified.`

Comment: Mmm ok, because it's out of your source tree. Then `add_subdirectory(../lib1 ../lib1/build)` - second argument is the build tree of your lib1. But again, don't do it.

Comment: If you want two targets that depend on each other, the easiest way to do so is to put them in one CMake project. FWIW, I've been working on projects where a "parent" `CMakeLists.txt` containing essentially some lines of `add_subdirectory` (plus some CMake fluff) were created by a script.

Comment: @pptaszni this doesn't work either. Thank you for your help anyways. The point why I  what root be cmake-agnostic is because in reality my lib2 is a ROS1 package built with catkin (cmake based build system) while there should be another lib3 that also uses lib1, but build with colcon (another cmake based build system, but for ROS2).

Comment: If they are ROS packages, then using `find_package` should be easier, because they should already be packed correctly. Then in your ROS xml you need some magic with `<build_depend>lib1</build_depend>`, I don't remember exact steps, but it should be feasible.

Comment: @pptaszni actually there is project on github that do the trick I try to do: kiss-icp. It has ROS-agnostic core in `cpp` folder and two warppers in `ros` folder: for ros1 and ros2, but I can't make it work like they do. Probably core lib (lib1) and wrappers (lib2) should have the same project names. Not quite sure.

Comment: @pptaszni doesn't `find_package(lib1)` require `lib1` to be build and installed beforehand? I want lib2 to trigger lib1 build. In kiss-iicp you just call `catkin build` or `colcon build` in the cmake/catkin/colcon agnostic root and it automatically choses right build system and builds cmake core with appropriate wrapper.

Comment: Yes, it requires. Both catkin and colcon should discover this dependency and schedule builds correctly. But I don't know how it will work when mixing the 2 together. Might indeed require some custom handmade script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test project with exe + lib:

```
cmake_agnostic_root/
|-- app/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- include/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- include/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- (there must be no CMakeLists.txt on this level)
```

It't bit ugly and need improvements but a good starting point

The exe CMakeList.txt:

```
project(app)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

include(ExternalProject)

if (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    # support multiple configurations: Debug and Release 
    set(TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX "<INSTALL_DIR>/$<CONFIG>")
    set(TEST_LIBRARY_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/$<CONFIG>/lib/test.lib)
    set(TEST_LIBRARY_HEADERS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/$<CONFIG>/include)
else()
    # single configuration: Debug or Release
    set(TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX "<INSTALL_DIR>")
    set(TEST_LIBRARY_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/lib/libtest.a)
    set(TEST_LIBRARY_HEADERS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/include)
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(test.proj
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib
    PREFIX test
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${TEST_LIBRARY_FILE}
)

add_library(test INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(test INTERFACE ${TEST_LIBRARY_HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(test INTERFACE ${TEST_LIBRARY_FILE})
add_dependencies(test test.proj)

add_executable(app src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app test)
```

The lib's CMakeList.txt:

```
project(test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_library(test src/test.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE include)

install(TARGETS test DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES include/test.h DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: I tried to follow your answer and `cmake` command runs without errors, but when I then try to create executable using `make` inside build folder it throws: `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'test//lib/test.lib', needed by 'app'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:111: CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2`

Comment: I used Visual Studio cmake generator that has 2 build configurations: debug and release. In your case probable there is no need to use $<CONFIG>

Comment: Also, try to add 
"BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/$<CONFIG>/lib/test.lib"
to ExternalProject_Add. It specifies that test.lib must be built by "test.proj" rule.

Comment: Also the problem can be in the library name: Windows: test.lib, Linux: libtest.a

Comment: I use VSCode on Ubuntu 22.04, so changing `test.lib` to `libtest.a` made it work, just as you said. I'm accepting your answer, but it would be nice if you elaborate on why it works with $<CONFIG>. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my example to work with Linux and Windows (MSVC). For MSVC (Visual Studio cmake generator) multiple build configuration is supported. $<CONFIG> - is just an alias for current build configuration (Debug or Release)

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in [KISS-ICP](https://github.com/PRBonn/kiss-icp). There should be such `set_global_target_properties` function called in `lib1` CMakeLists.txt. Not sure what it does, but there is its contents:

```
function(set_global_target_properties target)
  target_compile_features(${target} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
  target_compile_definitions(${target} PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>:_USE_MATH_DEFINES>)
  target_compile_options(
    ${target}
    PRIVATE # MSVC
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>:/W4>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>:/WX>
            # Clang/AppleClang
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-fcolor-diagnostics>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-Werror>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-Wall>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-Wextra>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-Wconversion>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,Clang,AppleClang>:-Wno-sign-conversion>
            # GNU
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-fdiagnostics-color=always>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Werror>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wall>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wextra>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-pedantic>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wcast-align>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wcast-qual>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wconversion>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Wdisabled-optimization>
            $<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>:-Woverloaded-virtual>)
  set(INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
  get_filename_component(INCLUDE_DIRS ${INCLUDE_DIRS} PATH)
  target_include_directories(${target} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                             PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${INCLUDE_DIRS}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)
endfunction()
```